Car from opposite lane comes barrelling down hillside into a head-on crash
I can only remember the movie opening: One car is travelling in one direction on a multi-lane highway. The opposite lane is much higher in elevation. A car from the higher elevation come barreling down the hillside straight into a head-on crash. The shot is taken from the front seat of the car on the lower elevation lane, so you witness the whole head-on collision. 
It's a 70's movie and possibly British. Any clue?

It could be Audrey Rose, (1977), which has a crash like that in the first 30 seconds of the movie.  Here is the full movie on Youtube.
